# optimise reading XML in c# web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to find a way to optimise the below code for my web service

In my webservice i recieve 10 different XML files, each xml file is always the same format, at the moment i have 10 different methods to handle each one, the below code is an example of one of the methods.

The only difference between the methods are the local variables and the node attributes.

Instead of having 10 methods almost identical i would like to have just one.

Can anyone advise on the best way to achieve this ?

```
public void NavigateXmlSessionData(XPathNavigator xPathNav)
{
    xPathNav.MoveToRoot();
    xPathNav.MoveToFirstChild();

    xPathNav.MoveToFirstChild();
    string  description, personId;

   // initalise vars
    description = "";
    personId = "";

    do
    {
        //display the child nodes
        if (xPathNav.MoveToFirstChild())
        {
            while (xPathNav.MoveToNext())
            {
                switch (xPathNav.Name)
                {
                    #region NodeAttributes
                    case "Description":
                        {
                            StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder(xPathNav.Value, 200);
                            description = strBuild.Replace('\'', ' ').ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    case "PersonId":
                        {
                            StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder(xPathNav.Value, 200);
                            personId = strBuild.Replace('\'', ' ').ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                        #endregion
                }
            }
            //move back to the parent
            xPathNav.MoveToParent();
        }

        ProcessRecord();
        // initalise vars
        description = "";
        personId = "";

    } while (xPathNav.MoveToNext());
}
```

Comment: XPath would probably help out a lot.

Comment: you might get better results from the code review site

Comment: What does the parent node of Description and PersonId look like? Is it Parent? Some sample Xml would be useful.

Comment: Sample XMLs would definitly help us out to understand your needs.